# Why are Viewers receiving an Access Denied message?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kusto-explorer

I have a security group which has the Viewer role for my database, however (some!) users and AAD apps within that group are receiving an "Access denied" message.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible errors like

- wrong User, wrong tenant ID
- restricted access policy enabled
- problems with AAD synch
- User is simply in wrong AAD group
- etc

It is necessary to have more information on this. A few questions you might want to ask:

1. is the error reproducible ?
2. is the error permanent per user, or does it change per user ?
3. check User data: `.show queries | where StartedOn > ago(48h)|  where User contains "myuser123" | project User, Application`.
4. Is the User query coming in via Web or via Kusto.Client or other (e.g.    python) ?
5. if a user uses the client, look at Connections - Inspect your AAD principal. Is the tenant ID the one would expect ?